# Geometric interpretation of Least Squares solution in an inconsistent system

Tags: geometry, least-squares

Let's say we have an inconsistent set of three linear equations in two variables. We can interpret these as three lines forming a triangle in the plane:

[image]

Let us write this in matrix form as

$$A \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = b$$

If we now "solve" this system by determining

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \hat x \\  \hat y \end{bmatrix} = \arg\min \left\Vert A \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} - b \right\Vert_2^2$$

is there a geometric interpretation of the point $(\hat x, \hat y)$ with respect to the triangle?

If so, is there a way to extend this notion to higher dimensions and/or more equations?

---

**EDIT:** I noticed that my quesiton was ill posed: You can scale any of the three equations with some nonzero factor and get a different minimizer so in that sense my original question was ill posed. Let us now assume that all the equations are normalized, that is, that each row vector of the matrix $A$ has norm $1$.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? Find the (x,y) that fits the Least Square requirement?

Comment: @Moti Because the system is inconsistent there is no solution, but we can find an approximate solution by solving the least squares problem. This is why I used quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rows of $A$ are normalized to 1, then the expression
$$ \left( A_i \left[ x \atop y\right] - b_i\right)^2,$$
where $A_i$ is the $i$th row of $A$, denotes the distance of [the point $(x,y)$ to the $i$th face of the polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line). Then,
$$\left\| A \left[ x \atop y\right]  -b \right\|^2$$
is the sum of the squared distances of the point $(x,y)$ to all faces of the polygon and you are looking for the point that minimizes this sum of distances.

In two dimensions, and with three lines, that would be the [symmedian, or Lemoine, point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmedianPoint.html).
[image: symmedian point]

Code to generate the figure

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.asarray([
  [2.0, 1.0],
  [-0.5, 1.0],
  [-3.0, 1.0]
])

b = np.asarray([-1.0,1.0,-2.0])

for i in range(np.size(A,0)):
  print(A[i,:])
  print(np.linalg.norm(A[i,:]))
  A[i,:] = A[i,:]/np.linalg.norm(A[i,:])
  print(A[i,:])

print(A)


def line(i, x):
  return (-b[i] + x*A[i,0])/A[i,1]

if __name__ == "__main__":

  x0 = -1.5
  x1 = 3

  plt.plot([x0, x1], [line(0,x0), line(0,x1)])
  plt.plot([x0, x1], [line(1,x0), line(1,x1)])
  plt.plot([x0, x1], [line(2,x0), line(2,x1)])

  p_hat = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(A.T,A)), np.dot(A.T, b))

  plt.scatter(p_hat[0], p_hat[1])
  plt.xlim(-1.5,5)
  plt.ylim(-3,4)
  plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
  plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm somehow not convinced: I just noticed that depending on how you scale each of the equations, you might get a different point. So if you scale e.g. the first equation with some $\varepsilon > 0$ and consider what happens for $\varepsilon \to 0$ the influence of this equation will decrease. In that sense my original question was ill posed.

Comment: Yes indeed, the distance from the point to the face needs to be normalized. Otherwise, you get the sum of distance weighted by the sum of the coefficients squared.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think now I understand your answer better. If we normalize the rows of $A$ (by their $l_2$-norm) we do indeed get the squared distances, and any scaling will scale the corresponding distance accordingly!